# Maps on Flutter

Tags: flutter, maps, mapbox

I'm about to start developing an app using Flutter that will have to show the best route using multiple destination points.

On [Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com) this is called [Optimized route](https://www.mapbox.com/help/optimization-api/) and I think this is called "Directions route optimization" on Google Maps.

The problem is that neither one has a ready to use plugin for Flutter.
I would like to know your opinion about what I should do because I have never tried to create a complex map on Flutter.

1. Use Google Maps through 'Platform Channel'
2. Use Mapbox through 'Platform Channel'
3. Give up?
4. Forget about Flutter?
5. None of the above

I have experience with Java (Android) and Swift (iOS), but I really want to do this using Flutter.

I just want a point of start. I appreciate any help.

Comment: It's not clear what part of flutter_map or google_maps_flutter won't work for you, when you say they aren't ready to use.

Comment: The "Optimized route" feature (read the second paragraph). I did search about this implementation and seems like there is nothing ready, just static maps and simple routes.

Comment: The API Optimised route can just be called via an http request, so no library is needed there. Then you can just parse the JSON response and build a polyline in flutter_map for example, and add to map.

Answer (score 2):

`google_maps_flutter` is at version 0.0.3, and claims:

> The plugin relies on Flutter's new mechanism for embedding Android and
>   iOS views. As that mechanism is currently in a developers preview,
>   this plugin should also be considered a developers preview.

`flutter_map` is not much better, at 0.0.4.

I understand that you want functionality that is not there yet, but Flutter hit 1.0 only a few weeks ago.  Have patience!

Answer (score 0):

To use maps in your flutter app, add google_maps_flutter as a dependency in your pubspec.yaml file.
 Follow the steps for usage of this plugin here:
https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter